# Is it possible to dynamicaly pass filters from a web app to embeded power BI report dataset and refresh report with new data based on those filters?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am new on using power bi and I have gone through some tutorials and samples on how to create a power bi Report. I have created a report for client POC using power bi desktop app. The datasourse for my report dataset is an Odata feed pointing to odata web api I have created that is filtered by certain parameters such as user Id. When designing  the report I have also created query parameters with default values and added them as Url parts to odata feed datasouce and they are working fine. The problem now that am facing is that I have now publish the report to power bi service and embeded to it to a webforms app using Power Bi service Api and Power Bi javacript .Now I want to know if is there a way i can pass parameter values such as a  logged in user Id and override the user id default value defined in my report so the user will only see his data on the report. The report should refresh data based on parameter sent from the my web app.

Thanks in advance.